# Binding a Set<String> in Guice

Tags: java, guice

I want to bind a Set in Guice like so:

```
public class TestModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        Set<String> testSet = Sets.newHashSet("Hello", "World");
        bind(Set.class).annotatedWith(Named.named("Test.Set")).toInstance(testSet);
    }
}
```

I have ensured that this module is being included when creating the injector. I try to use this bound Set later:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Inject
    public NewReleaseRunner(@Named("Test.Set") Set<String> testSet) {
        System.out.println(testSet.toString());
    }
}
```

However, this yields a failure: `No implementation for java.util.Set<java.lang.String> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=Test.Set) was bound.`

My concern is that `Set<String>` is generic, but the binding is to a `Set.class`. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using `@Provides` on a method in your module instead of binding in the config? The method can be specified to provide a `Set<String>`

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Using `@Provides` will work as desired but is not in the same code convention as the rest of our codebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two options. Replace

```
bind(Set.class).annotatedWith(Named.named("Test.Set")).toInstance(testSet);
```

with

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Set<String>>() {}).annotatedWith(Named.named("Test.Set")).toInstance(testSet);
```

**Or** remove the module's `configure()` binding and instead add

```
@Provides
@Named("Test.Set")
public Set<String> stringSet() {
    return Sets.newHashSet("Hello", "World");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw TypeLiteral around but was unsure how to use it